# Why does sys.getrefcount give huge values?

Tags: python

```
import sys

a = 10
b = a
print sys.getrefcount(a)
b=1
print sys.getrefcount(b)
```

output:

`22
614`

Is there any problem with my python interpreter? Why is this giving huge values like 614?

Python version

> /usr/lib/python2.7/

Comment: On QPython3, I get `29 355`.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I am new to Python. Is this accepted behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because CPython internally keeps an already created integer object with value 1 and internal variables point to it.
It makes sense to have only one such object since it is immutable.

The same thing applies to string literals, since they're immutable compilers generally keep a single unique string in memory and make variables point to it.

The more unique the literal, the less chance there is for it to be created internally.

```
>>> sys.getrefcount(1337)
3
>>> sys.getrefcount('p')
14
>>> sys.getrefcount('StackOverflow')
3
```

As you can see in the internals here, some small integer objects are created and cached for some small optimization.
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Objects/intobject.c#L74

Answer (score 0):

You can see the effects of Python's optimizations (see @Nether's answer) if you change the values to non-trivial ones. For instance, if your code is changed to:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys

a = 1012345
b = a
print(sys.getrefcount(a))
b=12345678
print(sys.getrefcount(b))
```

The output is:

```
5
4
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had this question. I read a blog post however that advises when you import a library (like `sys`), you're giving the environment access to all of the additional variables that this library also references, which is why you might see a prevalence of common integers like `128`, `256`, etc, when trying to count their references after importing any library.

For example, the integer `1` is referenced `129` times in the `sys` library (plus one for referencing that integer in code here):

```
import sys

print(sys.getrefcount(1))
# 130
```

However, I was puzzled by the example code that I was using to test the `getrefcount()` functionality:

```
import sys

print(sys.getrefcount("a highly unique string that certainly doesn't exist anywhere in sys, much less 3 times"))
# 3
```

The only way I can rationalize this code is by inferring from Python's inheritance scheme. This string of course inherits from the array class, which further inherits from the object class. So even though the string is singular and unique, there is a reference count of 3.

This is proven with a test on the initial code example:

```
import sys

a = 1

print(sys.getrefcount(1))
# 132
```

We expected this code to produce at least 130 references, but there are now two more, because `1` is a number, which inherits from object, and so adding the extra `a = 1` adds two more references to the number `1`.